# #ifdef to check if device is iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, if-statement, height, preprocessor

I wrote:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)

#ifdef IS_IPHONE_5
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 568
#else
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480
#endif
```

but it always return that device is iPhone 5... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/check-device-for-iphone-5.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `IS_IPHONE_5` macro is just fine. You can do things like this:

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
    // do something specific for iPhone 5
}
```

At compile time this code will be converted to:

```
if (([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)) {
}
```

The problem is your `SCREEN_HEIGHT` macros. The whole `#ifdef` block will be evaluated at compile time. Since you did define `IS_IPHONE_5`, the `SCREEN_HEIGHT` will always be set to 568.

You want a runtime determination of the screen height. You can get this from:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

Answer (score 2):

The screen height check must be done at run-time. #ifdef IS_IPHONE_5 will not be evaluated at run-time, but pre-compile time. You could call your screen height code as part of  a run-time method on a class.

you could just do something like

```
- (BOOL) isIphone5
{
    return ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0);
}
```

or as maddy suggests below

Comment: Can I use some other pre-processor statement to check if the device is iPhone 5?

Comment: The `IS_IPHONE_5` macro is just fine. It's the `SCREEN_HEIGHT` macros that are a problem.

Comment: No, Pre-processor directives are dealt with before the source code is compiled - therefore it's not going to be possible to determine what handset your application is running on. Due to this you will have to check the handset in a way like this answerer suggests.

Comment: @FergusMorrow The `#define` is just fine as-is. At compile time its use will be replaced with the definition of the macro. So in the end the resulting code will actually do a valid runtime check for the height of the iPhone 5 screen.

Comment: maddy - you are right, basicallly I meant the screen height check has to be done at run-time, using that macro would be fine, though at run-time.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, but he's using conditional preprocessor statements which have no effect at run time as their gone by the time the app is compiled..!

Answer (score 1):

Any directive beginning with `#` is dealt with by the pre-processor; so prior to the application even being compiled.

Now you are requiring run-time code to be executed in your definition; specifically - `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height`. Obviously this isn't going to be executed when the app isn't even compiled yet!

In most desktop applications where the `#ifdef` directive is used, it's because it's evaluated by the preprocessor at compile time from `#define` statements that are usually located in source files on the host machine. (That is, I will be compiling code for Mac OS X on a Mac OS X machine, therefore the preprocessor will find `#define` statements elsewhere to allow it recognise it's platform)

For what you're looking at doing you're going to have to detect the screensize when the app is actually running on a device; not prior to compile time - as after it is compiled it could be ran on any device.

The bottom line is **preprocessor conditional statements are only conditional at compile time - they can not change the execution once an app has been compiled; they become 'static' just like any other code you're compiling.**

Comment: Sorry but the `#define` is just fine as-is. See my answer for why.

Comment: Yes ```#define``` is - but not when it's being used for the conditional pre-processor statements.  The whole ```#ifdef```/```#ifndef``` idea isn't going to work as it's evaluated prior to compile, not at run-time. Thats the issue. To say otherwise is confusing the issue completely - as I make clear in my post the preprocessor **conditional statements** are only conditional at compile time; not the definition - but the actual conditional statements.

Comment: Right, see my answer. I explained this.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, I don't say there is anything wrong with ```#define``` - just using **preprocessor conditional statements**. Which we both appear to agree with..

Answer (score 1):

Try this define

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```